How do I suppress this Xcode static analyzer warning?
I am including the glm library in my Xcode project and want to suppress this warning:
/opt/extlibs/macosx/include/glm/./ext/../gtc/bitfield.inl:343:15: warning: Although the value stored to 'x' is used in the enclosing expression, the value is never actually read from 'x' [deadcode.DeadStores]
                uint16 REG2(x >>= 1);
                            ^     ~

Is there a way to do that via a #pragma or a #define or something else in the Build Settings?
Note: The static analyzer does not appear to obey the normal methods used to suppress compiler warnings, with command line flags, or #pragmas.

If you want to suppress the warning through the build settings you could try setting "Other Warning Flags" > "-Wno-unused-variable".

@l'L'l The Xcode static analyser seems to use different flags to the normal compiler warnings.   It doesn't appear to have any inline way of suppressing warnings you have no control over;  I've spent a fair amount of time looking to see how do it...

have you tried #pragma with -Wno-unused-variable? The other thing that comes to mind is another compiler flag could be overriding it because of the order. If you want to post your clang build command I can take a further look.

@l'L'l Sorry I missed your reply; I will try that shortly.
